# A way to tell how much cumulative processing a script uses

Tags: linux, macos, cpu

I was going to install a script on my web hosting account, and they said they were concerned that it would take too much CPU to run.

I know you can monitor the instantaneous use of a process with `top` or `ps`, but is there a way to log how much total CPU demand (not sure the units here) a script takes from start to finish?

I would be interested in a -nix solution for linux or OSX command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would be interested in a -nix solution for linux or OSX command-line.

I have no OS X to test with, but as for the linux part: [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)

Example:

```
FreeBSD:/home/hennes/test>time ls
real  0m0.003s
user  0m0.000s
sys   0m0.002s
```

Ofcourse rather than ls you would use your script or program. Run it somewhere where you can log information (e.g. in [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html), [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) it or redirect its output. Let it run long enough to collect data and then stop it (e.g. <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, kill SIGHUP, ...)

Alternatively <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> might yield information about the process, though that is also untested on OS X and on Linux.

Comment: Great! That does what I need and works in OSX too.